# How to setup Xbox Series S|X for a family?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

I'm new to Xbox and have created an account for me and my children and have linked them to as a family.

- Will all members of the family be able to play if I login and setup the Xbox with my account? is there a main user or should we all just sign in?
- Will we be able to share games purchased with my account? or should we purchase games for the child accounts and share those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by setting the specific console as **"Your home Xbox"**. You can find more details on how to setup it and what it covers in the help article [here](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/console/my-home-xbox).

Since you went through the process and created accounts for everyone under yours as family members, I would suggest that you add all accounts and everyone should be logging in with their account so you can have the age and other protections and permissions coming with the family management.

After setting the console as **Home Xbox**, all added accounts should be able to play all games and share all subscriptions (Xbox Game Pass for example) without you being logged in to the console.